# SQL problem, need to add new condition to my current code

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

in the following table I am capturing the same ID recorded on different dates , in which  Column A is returning "Yes' for both entries but I want to add a filter/condition in my current Sql code in which if there is a difference of 90 days in between the current record date and previously record date then I want Column A to return 'NO' for most recent record date or most recent entry.

| ID | Column A | Record date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Yes | 2022-07-11 12:05:34.067-07:00 |
| 001 | Yes | 2022-02-01 10:08:34.067-07:00 |

Comment: Can there be more than 2 rows per ID?

Comment: why same id is repeating?

Comment: @Equinox there are multiple rows which can have same ID  but differentiator between them is Column A. So for example if Task with ID 001 already accepted then  column A will return Yes but if the same task is repeating again after 90 days ( most recently for different factors) then I want column to return NO.

Comment: @Madmax As ID is representing different task and there can be multiple factors due to which a task can repeat so if its repeating again after 90 days , I want it to mark as No in Column A

Comment: @newbie you want to do this with only SQL ?

Comment: @Madmax yes i want to add it to my current SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below query:

```
with sample_data as (
  select 001 as ID, 'Yes' as ColumnA, timestamp('2022-07-11 12:05:34.067-07:00') as RecordDate
  union all select 001 as ID, 'Yes' as ColumnA, timestamp('2022-02-01 10:08:34.067-07:00') as RecordDate
)

select 
  ID,
  if(
    date_diff(RecordDate,lag(RecordDate) over (partition by ID order by RecordDate),day) > 90, 
    'No','Yes') as ColumnA,
  RecordDate
from sample_data
```

Output:

[image]